# Nodemailer: Cannot find module 'net' + nodemailer.createTransport is not a function

Tags: vue.js, nodemailer

I am unable to understand why nodemailer is not working properly within a VUE.js app.
The code is from the nodemailer examples. Here is the method I call on form submit:

```
methods: {
        submit() {
            this.$refs.form.validate().then(() => {
                "use strict";
                const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
                async function main() {
                    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                        host:'mail.kakakakak',
                        port: 465,
                        secure: true,
                        auth: {
                            user: 'info@', 
                            pass: '****' 
                        }
                    });
                    // send mail with defined transport object
                    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
                        from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
                        to: "info@lopezi.com", 
                        subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
                        text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
                        html: "<b>Hello world?</b>" // html body
                    });

                    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
                }

                main().catch(console.error);
            });
        },
   }
```

The first time I click the submit button I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'net'
at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./node_modules/defaultable sync recursive (app.5176eebb0babf67e88fb.hot-update.js:22), <anonymous>:2:10)
at Object.workaround_require (defaultable.js?6987:49)
at require (defaultable.js?6987:77)
at eval (server.js?663d:9)
at defaulter (defaultable.js?6987:83)
at defaultable (defaultable.js?6987:63)
at good (defaultable.js?6987:174)
at Object.eval (server.js?663d:5)
at eval (server.js:242)
at Object../node_modules/hbo-dnsd/server.js (chunk-vendors.5176eebb0babf67e88fb.hot-update.js:2053)
```

The second time I click the submit button, still with the same content in there  I get the error:

```
TypeError: nodemailer.createTransport is not a function
at _callee$ (ContactForm.vue?2be1:64)
at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:45)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:271)
at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:97)
at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?3b8d:5)
at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?3b8d:27)
at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?3b8d:34)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at new F (_export.js?63b6:36)
at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?3b8d:23)
```